# DC.js Barchart- provide tooltip or title on the X axis labels

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm working on a barchart from dc.js. I'm having trouble providing a tooltip or a title on the labels X axis.

The reason why I need axis tooltips is that I added a feature to text labels that reaches a maximum length and it will apply the '...' into it. The tooltip will help the users to view the full text of that X axis Text labels. Here are the following that i have done but it didnt work.

- I use chart.selectAll(g.x text) **or .text and add an .on('mouseover', ...) function which that didn't work. I look at the developer tool and i see the events when i select the  element for the labels but its not appearing when i hover over it.
- I manually added an attribute of 'onMouseOver' and its function and that also didn't work. Here is the code I used. The getTooltip function have a console.log message to see if it triggers.

  chart.selectAll('g.x text')
           .attr('transform', 'translate(-40,20) rotate(315)') 
            .attr('onMouseOver', 'getTooltip(this)');
- I added a `title` attribute when I selectAll(g.x text) but that didn't work.

I'm running out of ideas and this needs to be done soon. Please can you assist me?

Is it possible to have a tooltip or a title on the X axis labels for barchart dc.js?

Thank you. Here is the code I did below.

```
        barchart
    .title(function(v) {
        var total = d3.format(',d') ( v.value.Total );
        return lve_cit_bucketsLookup[v.key] + " Total:" + total;
    }).renderlet(function (chart) {
       // rotate x-axis labels
     chart.selectAll('g.x text')
         .attr('transform', 'translate(-40,20) rotate(315)') 
         /* .attr('onMouseOver', 'getTooltip(this)') */;

       // works with .tick
        chart.selectAll('g.x text')
        .on('mouseover', function(d){
                console.log("mouseover fool: " + d) 
            div.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", .9);
            div.html("dest")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
         .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px"); 
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d) {
             div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        }); 

   })
    .xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {
        var getLookup = lve_cit_bucketsLookup[v];
        if(getLookup.length > 10)
            return getLookup.substring(0,10) + '...';
        else
            return getLookup;
        });
```

By the way, I used the .on('mouseover', ...) function when I selectAll(x axis text labels) for the heatmap dc.js and it works like a charm. But I'm still having trouble for this barchart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dc.js blocks pointer events on its axes [in its CSS](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/d06bd9e6cefdd6a867370079bbc4205785b1e3f9/style/dc.scss#L177).

I think this was a heavy-handed way to stop the text from accidentally being selected, which nowadays would better be addressed with `user-select: none`. ([I've filed an issue to investigate this.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1358))

It's [explicitly re-enabled for heatmaps](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/d06bd9e6cefdd6a867370079bbc4205785b1e3f9/style/dc.scss#L236) because of the select row or column feature, which is why that worked for you.

Anyway, you can add your own CSS rule to override dc.js like this:

```
.dc-chart g.axis text {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

and you should start getting those mouse events again!