# D3.js Dc.js Binding Event listener to axis tick label

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a fundamental needs to bind an event listener to the label of each tick in my chart (not axis label, but the data label on each tick). 
Let's take this chart for example.

http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/ordinal-bar.html

I want to put something like,

```
 *.on('click', function(){console.log("click!")})
```

to each fruit name on a axis (such as, when I click on "apple" or "banana"... text, it should listen to my click. I have been trying few attempts but all failed, such as :

```
d3.selectAll("g.axis.x g.tick text").on("click", function(){console.log("Mouse click")})
```

Can you help to show me if anyway can resolve this?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Different question with I think the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48067753

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. Hope it can be noted in DC.js documentation.

Comment: It doesn't need to be documented. [It needs to be fixed.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1358)

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon

Thanks for forwarding me to the right answer here:

[DC.js Barchart- provide tooltip or title on the X axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48065043/dc-js-barchart-provide-tooltip-or-title-on-the-x-axis-labels/48067753#48067753)

REASON: dc.js blocks pointer events on its axes in its CSS. 
SOLUTION: Adding css

```
.dc-chart g.axis text {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select all the `text` elements when you call the `xAxis`

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .on('click', barClick);

function barClick(){
    alert('click')
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(formatPercent);



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').innerHTML);

//d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.frequency;
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll('text')  
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .on('click', barClick);

function barClick() {
  alert('click')
}

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  })

//});

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" id="data">
  [{
      "letter": "A",
      "frequency": 0.08167
    },
    {
      "letter": "B",
      "frequency": 0.01492
    },
    {
      "letter": "C",
      "frequency": 0.02780
    },
    {
      "letter": "D",
      "frequency": 0.04253
    },
    {
      "letter": "E",
      "frequency": 0.12702
    },
    {
      "letter": "F",
      "frequency": 0.02288
    },
    {
      "letter": "G",
      "frequency": 0.02022
    },
    {
      "letter": "H",
      "frequency": 0.06094
    },
    {
      "letter": "I",
      "frequency": 0.06973
    },
    {
      "letter": "J",
      "frequency": 0.00153
    },
    {
      "letter": "K",
      "frequency": 0.00747
    },
    {
      "letter": "L",
      "frequency": 0.04025
    },
    {
      "letter": "M",
      "frequency": 0.02517
    },
    {
      "letter": "N",
      "frequency": 0.06749
    },
    {
      "letter": "O",
      "frequency": 0.07507
    },
    {
      "letter": "P",
      "frequency": 0.01929
    },
    {
      "letter": "Q",
      "frequency": 0.00098
    },
    {
      "letter": "R",
      "frequency": 0.05987
    },
    {
      "letter": "S",
      "frequency": 0.06333
    },
    {
      "letter": "T",
      "frequency": 0.09056
    },
    {
      "letter": "U",
      "frequency": 0.02758
    },
    {
      "letter": "V",
      "frequency": 0.01037
    },
    {
      "letter": "W",
      "frequency": 0.02465
    },
    {
      "letter": "X",
      "frequency": 0.00150
    },
    {
      "letter": "Y",
      "frequency": 0.01971
    },
    {
      "letter": "Z",
      "frequency": 0.00074
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: This is a d3-only answer. It may not have been clear, but the question was about dc.js.

Comment: @Gordon Oh I&#39;m sorry. I got confused there.
What OP can do is create the axis and ticks using d3.js instead of dc.js. I dont know how dc.js works but this should work.
Thanks and cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, aditya.kk29.
However, my concern is to do with charts built by DC.js
Such as using the example in the page that provided, how could we bind the event listener to it.